# ParseObject save in background error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

When I try to save a ParseObject in the background (using Parse Android SDK) it throws the following error (note: Offline storage is enabled):

Update :
Created my subclass by extending ParseObject and calling a SaveInBackground method.

> Parse SDK version :  com.parse:parse-android:1.15.1

```
 com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the Offline Store.
                                                                        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:114)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the Offline Store.
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using ? Provide the code that causes the exception

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Changelog doesn't mention any fixes related to that issue but you should still update to the latest version: `1.16.0`

Comment: instead of SaveInBackground if I used saveEventually  then its working. Is there any reason?